# Tanka/Jsonnet import in parentheses

Tags: jsonnet

I've started to play with the Tanka and can't find anywhere the answer to the question:

**What** is difference **between**

```
(import "my.jsonnet")
```

**and**

```
import "my.jsonnet"
```

and why the following construction is valid:

```
(import "my.jsonnet") + (import "my1.jsonnet")
```

but this one isn't:

```
import "my.jsonnet" + import "my1.jsonnet"
```

What role do the parentheses play here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax matter:

```jsonnet
import "my.jsonnet" + import "my1.jsonnet"
```

gives below error

```
file.jsonnet:1:8-43 Computed imports are not allowed
```

because that line is interpreted as if you were trying to overload `"my.jsonnet"` with the `+` that follows it, i.e. for the interpreter it'd look similar to:

```
import "my" + ".jsonnet";
```

which would (more obviously) trigger above error regarding import filenames requirement to be "static" strings.